# Реализация анимации при скролле страницы

Tags: css, анимация

Всем доброго времени суток,

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kalebra/sx03krty/1/

```
AOS.init();

$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($('.fir').offset().top >= '2039') {
            $('.opp-imgs').addClass('smaller');
        } else {
            $('.opp-imgs').removeClass('smaller');
        }
    });
});
```

Также выложил на хостинг:
https://meetup13.000webhostapp.com/

Нужно реализовать анимацию картинок с правой стороны. Использовал AOS - Animate On Scroll. Я в этом новичок. Работает всё как-то не стабильно и не адаптивно - только при ширине экрана 1440px анимация отрабатывает более менее, при других значениях уже появляются проблемы. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как правильно это реализовать? Может стоит использовать какое-то другое решение?

Comment: Я смотрю с планшета и отлично работает ...за что плюс вам